# Form POST in CodeIgniter won't be sent

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a `<select>` box with 3 `<option>` items generated within CodeIgniter's Form Helper

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="selectCatsByComponent">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">-- Choose a component --</option>
    <option value="1">Content</option>
    <option value="2">E-commerce</option>
</select>
```

When I select the option from a dropdown list *Content* or *E-Commerce*, it redirects with appropriate `<option>` value correctly to the page with `categories/get_categories/$ID`. But whenever I select the first option, which actually also have a `value="0"`, it redirects me to `categories/get_categories/` without the ID instead redirecting me to `categories/get_categories/0`... I just can't the problem.

Here is my controller `Categories.php`:

```
public function get_categories($pid = 0, $com_id = 0){
    ...

    // Check if Filter sends some POST data
    if( $this->input->post('selectCatsByComponent') ){
        echo '1';
        $com_id = $this->input->post('selectCatsByComponent');
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('selectCatsByComponent' => $com_id));
    }else
        echo '2';
        $this->session->set_userdata(array('selectCatsByComponent' => $com_id));

    // Get processed data results
    $componentData['selectedComponent'] = $com_id;
    $componentData['selectComponents']  = $this->component_model->get_components();
    $componentData['items']             = $this->category_model->getCategoryList($pid, $com_id);

    ...
}
```

And `categories_model.php`:

```
public function get_categories($parent = FALSE, $com_id = FALSE){

    // SQL command
    $this->db->select('id, com_id');
    $this->db->order_by('categories.ordering', 'ASC');

    // Check if parent ID exist
    if( $parent !== FALSE ) $this->db->where('pid', $parent);

    // Check if component ID exist
    if( $com_id != FALSE ) $this->db->where('com_id', $com_id);

    // Alphabetize results if no ordering present
    $this->db->order_by('title', 'ASC');

    $query = $this->db->get('categories');

    // Check row existance in DB table
    if( $query->result() < 1 ) return FALSE;

    // Get results in object type
    $result = $query->result();

    $categories = array();
    $components = array();
    foreach($result as $cat){
        $categories[] = $this->get_category($cat->id);
        $components[] = $this->get_component($cat->com_id);

    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Pls, could someone tell me what I'am doing wrong here ? Why it wont POST the form? Inside controller's function, i made a Conditional statement, where I echo out the number's. Whenever I select the option it show's me `echo 1`, except for first option from dropdown list, which shows me `echo 2`. What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if( $this->input->post('selectCatsByComponent') )`

should become

`if( $this->input->post('selectCatsByComponent') !== false )`

because 0 is considered false in PHP.

Small update:

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a list of everything that PHP considers `false` and where you should use [comparison by type (also known as strict comparison)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). A nice article [here](http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/).

Comment: Oh man I love you! Thank you so much for clarify it, I didn't know about this at all.

Comment: No problem, also pay attention to empty strings, arrays, "0", etc... They are all considered false, so you need to compare them by type as well. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).